# How does Java implement the moveToPrevious method on Cursor?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I came across a method on `Cursor` called [`moveToPrevious()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToPrevious%28%29).

I had previously read an [article](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor) which suggested that implementing a backwards version of the [C SQLite step command](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_step) would be hard / impossible:

> ... asking for an sqlite3_step_backward() button is really like expecting your symbolic debugger to be able to run backwards or to "undo" its execution back to the previous breakpoint. Nobody reasonably expects debuggers to be able to do this, so you shouldn't expect SQLite to be able to sqlite3_step_backward() either.

- Is an Android cursor a wrapper around SQLite or some kind of a independent implementation?
- How how have thay made this moveToPrevious command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android `Cursor` class indeed reads all result records into memory first, and then allows you to step through them randomly.

(This is why there is the 1 MB limit on data in a cursor.)

Comment: Ok fair enough.  I guess if this causes a causing a memory issue you could use a batching strategy with limit and offset?

Comment: Yes; but if you're trying to use more than 1 MB of data at once on a phone, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Cursor interface provides random read-write access to the result set returned by a database query. Cursor implementations are not required to be synchronized so code using a Cursor from multiple threads should perform its own synchronization when using the Cursor.

Cursor: Retrieving data from SQLite databases in Android is done using Cursors. The Android SQLite query method returns a Cursor object containing the results of the query.Cursors store query result records in rows and grant many methods to access and iterate through the records.To use Cursors android.database.Cursor must be imported.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

Check the source here

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/database/Cursor.java/

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/database/AbstractCursor.java/

Look at the line 248 in the link

```
248 public final boolean moveToPrevious() {
249        return moveToPosition(mPos - 1); 
         // mPos looks like is the index here which is an int
250    }
```

moveToPosition

```
195      public final boolean moveToPosition(int position) {
196        // Make sure position is not past the end of the cursor
197        final int count = getCount();
198        if (position >= count) {
199            mPos = count;
200            return false;
201        }
202
203        // Make sure position isn't before the beginning of the cursor
204        if (position < 0) {
205            mPos = -1;
206            return false;
207        }
208
209        // Check for no-op moves, and skip the rest of the work for them
210        if (position == mPos) {
211            return true;
212        }
```

`getCount()`

Returns the current position of the cursor in the row set. The value is zero-based. When the row set is first returned the cursor will be at positon -1, which is before the first row. After the last row is returned another call to next() will leave the cursor past the last entry, at a position of count().

Returns:
the current cursor position.

Comment: How does that work?  They step though the whole result set first and copy it into memory?

Comment: How do they get random read-write access to the result set returned by a database query?  ResultSets are queried sequentially in the C API.

Comment: @Robert Look at the source code in the link and check the edited answer.

Comment: @Robert Result sets of queries are returned in Cursor objects. so query only those columns that you need. Based on the position you can get the desired result. mPos in the position intially its -1. see the `getCount` method.